# Using simple shapes, how do I recreate Twitter's in-feed reply icon?

Tags: icon

Trying to recreate Twitter's reply icon:

[image]

**But how do I get that handle bar right using clean geometry?**

Right now I'm using two circles:

[image]

But in the end it doesn't quite feel right:

[image]

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that icon is from the "rosettaicons" font family. When zoomed in (i used firebug in lieu of actually grabbing the font pack), you see all the rounded edges:

[image: Screenshot of zoomed-in icon]

The closest I got to simple geometry ended up like this:

[image: Basic geometry]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Indeed - parts of a circle plus a line with the same thickness seems to be exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this Twitter icon:

[image: https://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/cms/intents/icons/reply_hover.png]

(From https://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/cms/intents/icons/reply_hover.png)

[image]

Two ellipses, a rectangle, a triangle, and a sheared rectangle (parallelogram).

1. The larger ellipse minus the smaller ellipse
2. Minus the rectangle.
3. Combine with the triangle
4. Minus the parallelogram.

Alternate style as per https://www.google.com.au/search?q=twitter+reply+icon:

[image: Reply icon geometry]

Two ellipses, a rectangle and a triangle.

1. The larger ellipse minus the smaller ellipse
2. Minus the rectangle.
3. Combine with the triangle.

Comment: Nice, but how do I make it **exactly** like that Twitter icon?

Comment: Again this is not the icon I requested / the one Twitter uses.